# How to redock the Firebug panel, Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, windows-7

I did not know where I should ask this question. I somehow undocked firebug 1.11.4 but cannot redock it and it is so hard to use as a floating panel. I have googled this and found I am not the only one with this problem. One person asked for a redock button to be added to firebug. Please help this is slowing my work.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the Firebug button in the menu configuration, then click the button to get a menu with the positions:

[image]

This is the German edition. :) The top item (*Abgedockt*) is *floating*, the others are *top*, *bottom*, *left* and *right*.